# What is meant by a geometrically connected curve?

Tags: functions, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

I am studying about Drinfeld Modules for my Master's thesis,but I have not yet learnt about schemes and algebraic geometry.The set-up for Drinfeld modules,according to Goss' Basic structures of Function Field Arithmetic says that we first start with a smooth projective geometrically connected curve over a finite field $F_r$?

I've hunted high and low googling for a definition,but all I couldn't find anything.

If anyone could help ,I'd be very grateful

Comment: Geometrically connected: after base change by any field extension remains connected.

Comment: Thanks! I had seen someone post this question on mathoverflow but I didn't really get it then,suddenly I do now!

Comment: Note that it suffices to know that your curve is connected after base change by the algebraic closure.

Comment: Amendment to a previous post to @A.G.

Comment: To the previous (edited) post (I suppose you already realize it, but anyway): EGA IV, Corollaire 4.4.6.

Comment: Right , thanks.